# A select list of user created nodes

Tags: entities, commerce

I am creating a commerce store for custom clothing. I am trying to implement a product line item where users are posed with a dropdown of their uploaded artwork via a select list. I have created a content type called artwork that users will create. Now I just need to create a field that is a dropdown list of user-created nodes of artwork type. Does anyone know how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the purpose of that dropdown, you should have a look at the [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:
>
> - A generic entity reference field
> - Four widgets:
>
>   - Two implemented on top of the Options module (Select and Radios/Checkboxes),
>   - Two autocomplete widgets (one with one text field per entry, one tag-style with comma-separated entries in the same text field)
> - Two formatters:
>
>   - A "Label" formatter, with optional link that displays the label of the referenced entity (the node title, the user name, etc.)
>   - A "Rendered entity" formatter, that renders the references entity using a configurable view mode
> - Integration with Views (for both forward and backward references)
> - Integration with Entity Metadata (and as a consequence with Search API and the like)
> - Integration with Devel generate
> - Integration with Feeds and Migrate (>= 2.3) for painless data import